# Show that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} $

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to prove that 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} $$

My teacher suggested to use 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^{t}}\sum_{n\geq 0 }e^{nt} \, \mathrm{d}t $$
But I don't understand why both integrals would be equal.

Comment: Consider the geometric series.

Answer (score 7):

As written in the OP, your instructor has provided an incorrect series representation of the integrand. In fact, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nt}$ diverges for $t\ge 0$.

Instead, we first write $\frac{1}{e^t-1}=\frac{e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}$. Then proceeding, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}\,dt&=\int_0^\infty \frac{te^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty te^{-(n+1)t}\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\int_0^\infty te^{-t}\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Preliminaries:

$\frac {1}{1-x} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\\
\frac {1}{1-e^x} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} (e^{x})^n = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx}$

And for our problem:

$\frac {t}{{e^t}-1} = \frac {te^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}  = te^{-t}\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}  e^{-nx} = t\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}  e^{-nx}$

Since integration is a "linear operator" we can integrate each term, and sum the results.

that is: $\int (\sum f(t)) dt = \sum (\int f(t) dt)$

$\int_0^\infty t e^{-nt} dt = \frac {1}{n^2}$

$\sum \frac {1}{n^2} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: Thank you too. I appreciate your help. Very detailed reply.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you get
$$\int_0^\infty t\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nt}\,dt
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty te^{-nt}\,dt.$$
This is an integral one can actually "do".